# Multiple databases vs. one database with IDs used to separate organizations

Tags: database, database-design, architecture

In the situation of a web application that organizations can sign up for and use to manage data, what are the pros and/or cons of the two following options?

- **One database per organization** where the data for each organization is entirely separated into individual databases, with one (very small) centralized database that keeps a basic listing of the organizations and their database identifiers.
- **One database for the entire application** where all the entities are stored in one large database and separated using an organization identifier column on each table.

Some other aspects to consider:

- Data will never be shared between organizations in the database, nor will login credentials.
- Some organizations will allow the general public to register an account with the application to submit data, others will not.
- We plan on exposing a public API for organizations to integrate their current processes with our application. Organizations will be able to generate API keys to allow access to their data, but there won't be a public API that spans organizations.
- Companies will be storing potentially sensitive data in the application.

From your experience and/or knowledge, what is the right way to go about this design decision (or is there a "right" way at all?)

Comment: You might find Joel Spolsky's comments on this topic interesting. Here's a transcript of the podcast in which Joel discussed the multi-tenant database architecture of Fogbugz: https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W24218 (search the transcript for the question starting at [50:45])

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170530080303/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx) is an in-depth discussion on MSDN (Multi-Tenant Data Architecture).

I would add that there is no right/wrong way. It all depends on requirements, existing expertise and cost.

Answer (score 0):

One consideration that might be interesting:

if you have a single database for all orgs, and those orgs are spread all across the 24 time zones, then this requires a 24/24 (and perhaps 7/7) DBMS.  Not all products have that, I believe.