# Big database vs multiple databases

Tags: php, mysql, database, yii

I have new produces about 9 products every product  have something shared with another on database

for example :

1- users databases content :

- users information table(email,username,...etc)
- users groups table(groups permissions )
- users images table
- ... etc

2- for example news database content data related to users database like " writer ID "

3- another product also content data related to user id in users database

I have tow solutions :

1- Add database for every product (but relations will be problem here and slow "tested under Yii framework ")

2- Add all products on one big database (I like this solution because it save time in 
working with relation under " Yii framework " but what about performance )

I need to know what different between tow solutions related to  :

1- relations

2- performance

3- security

4- management

5- storage size

I read this articles but all results not very clear :
[first link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4547/designing-a-platform-one-database-or-multiple-databases)
[second link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115233/multiple-databases-vs-one-database-with-ids-used-to-separate-organizations)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a new db for each product is anti-relational, and if you have a reasonable number of products, all mantaining operations will become impossible! Please, don't do it! :)

RELATIONS: MySQL allows to create foreign keys acroos 2 different databases.

PERFORMANCE: The number of databases does not affect performance.

SECURITY: The number of databases does not affect security... except that you can't set permissions on individual databases, if you have 99999 databases.

MANAGEMENT: Again: don't.

STORAGE SIZE: Yes, having multiple databases have a size (becuase you have more tables). But, unless you plan to use compression, this is not the real problem.

Comment: Federico,for size i will use same tables count , just my real problem in relations . 
So you advise me to use multiple databases ?

Comment: No, I think that 1 db is ok, and it's probably the simplest solution.

Comment: it's simplest  but i guess it's bad in management ,storage ,performance  and backup , because the data will be about 200K in every table .

Comment: A 200K table is not big. It's perfectly reasonable. Having more databases does not improve performance in any way.